# Extracting data using regexp_extract in Hive

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

```
{'offercode': u'5100003454', 'offer': 'Book 14 days in Advance and Get 15% Off\r\n', 'original_baseprice': [[3700.0], [3700.0]], 'taxbreakup': {'taxinfo': {'othertaxon_display': u'Sell Rate', 'servtax': 0.0, 'luxtaxon_display': u'Sell Rate', 'servtaxon_display': u'Sell Rate', 'nettservicetaxflag': True, 'servtaxon': u'sellrate', 'othertax': 0.0, 'taxonextrabedflag': True, 'luxtaxon': u'sellrate', 'taxincluded': False, 'taxcode': u'7500003113', 'luxtax': 18.66, 'othertaxon': u'sellrate'}, 'LT': 1174, 'OT': 0, 'ST': 0}, 'baseprice': [[3145.0], [3145.0]], 'success': True, 'extraguest': [[0], [0]], 'extraguest_nett': [[0], [0]], 'original_nettbreakup': [[2775.0], [2775.0]], 'original': [[3700.0], [3700.0]]}
```

I'm not able to fetch 'LT': 1174, 'OT': 0, 'ST': 0 value in hive

I already try this

regexp_extract(string,"\'LT\': (.*?) ", 1) as LT, regexp_extract(string,"\'OT\': (.*?) ", 1) as OT, regexp_extract(string,"\'ST\': (.*?) ", 1)

Comment: @shapiroyaacov i use regexp_extract(string,"\'LT\': (.*?) ", 1) as LT,
regexp_extract(string,"\'OT\': (.*?) ", 1) as OT,
regexp_extract(string,"\'ST\': (.*?) ", 1) as ST problem integer value come with quama and bracke }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
regexp_replace(regexp_extract(string,"\'LT\': (.*?) ", 1), ',', '') as LT,
regexp_replace(regexp_extract(string,"\'OT\': (.*?) ", 1), ',', '') as OT,
regexp_replace(regexp_extract(string,"\'ST\': (.*?) ", 1 ), '},', '') as ST
```

Comment: While code-only answers are better than no answers at all, please understand that they are not recommended. Try to explain what the code does, and/or why it works.